How do you find the end point of an arc with a non - zero starting angle in cartesian coordinates.
I know the starting angle of the arc $θ_p$, the change in angle or central angle Δθ, the arc length $a$, and the starting $x$, $y$ pair.  I would like to find the coordinate pair $x_1$, $y_1$.  I only need a formula as this is needed for code.

When I tried to approach this I tried to find the center point using a vector of $\theta_p$ and the radius and then add on the vector of $\Delta\theta$ and the radius.  I used $r = (a / \Delta\theta)$; $x_c = (cos(\theta_p) * r) + x$; $y_c = (sin(\theta_p) * r) + y$$ $$x_1 = (cos(\Delta\theta) * r) + x_c$; $y_1 = (sin(\Delta\theta) * r) + y_c.$
When I tried this my computer gave me very large numbers orders of magnitude too big that would go up by a consistent rate and I want to know if it was because of my original math.

I suppose you do want to make sure your $\Delta\theta$ is measured in radians for your first equation to hold, but you've probably checked that already.
Are you using the "standard mathematical" model of $\theta=0$ pointing due east and increasing $\theta$ moving counterclockwise/anticlockwise? If so, you would have (for instance) $x = x_c + r\cos\theta_p$, which would solve to $x_c = x-r\cos\theta_p$ rather than what you have.
And then finally, to find your new point $(x_1,y_1)$ you should use the actual angle ($\theta_p+\Delta\theta$), not just the change in angle.

The previous theta is based on the previous theta before it + delta theta.  Which is started at zero when the screen turns on and the process continuously happens finding the next theta each iteration.  So theta = 0 is just where ever the screen starts if that is what you are looking for.  If you are talking about the graph then it is equal to the y axis.  And the theta increases when moving right or clockwise.  Hope that helps.

@user26401639 in your picture, your ray is moving to the right, and counter-clockwise (which, counterclockwise is what you want if you want to use the standard breakdown) -- unless you're using some weird window coordinates where the top-left corner of your screen is (0,0) and positive y is downward?

Sorry for your confusion this is for a robotics application and the screen is just the computer that runs it and this formula is meant to be run multiple time a second to update the x, y and theta variables for the next calculation.  The coordinate system is based off of the initial position.  I would like to make a correction though the angle does go up when turning left or counter clockwise which I got wrong in the first comment

When you say $$x_c = x - r * cos(/theta_p)$$ does that mean to also subtract from $x_c$ in the final two equations or just in the equations to find the center.

@user26401639 right, well then assuming you've got your coordinate system set up to be normal with respect to angles, then both those things would need to be fixed (i.e. your equations for $x_c$ and $y_c$ wouldn't match, and you'd need to keep accumulating your angle). ETA based on above: right, the actual formula for $x_c$ is $x-r\cos\theta_p$, not what you had originally.

Or to put it another way, $x = x_c + r\cos\theta$ is true for all your points, both your original $(x,y)$ and your new $(x_1,y_1)$, since that's how rotation around a point goes.

Ok so the final calculations for $x_1$ are $$x_c = x - r * cos(\theta_p)$$ $$x_1 = x_c + r * cos(\theta_p + \Delta\theta)$$ and the y equations are the same but with sin

That's what it looks like from here!
